# jQuery prepend() function alternative in php

Tags: php, jquery

I want to switch a task of jQuery to PHP.

Earlier it was like :

```
myString +=  "Hello There ! ";
$("#latestRoutes").prepend(myString).slideDown(2000);
```

But now As I am switching to PHP, How can I do the $.prepend function in PHP to append a variable to a particular string ?

Comment: `$mystring .='Your data';` in php

Comment: No. I tried this one. But I want to append this to a particular div only.

Comment: Find where in the page the `latestRoutes` element is being generated and add the text to the beginning of it. (The `slideDown` part, of course, cannot be done server-side.) Unless you're using [one of the PHP DOM parsers](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=php+dom+parser), you don't have a DOM on the server, so you can't manipulate it the way you do on the client. But that's fine, just modify the part generating the element in the first place.

Comment: you mean echo ? What if I want to add stuff in a loop. What then ?

Comment: I don't understand why the downvote. its a valid question. You people want the answer in the question itself ? huh ?

Comment: "We people" are volunteers, some may think **your** efforts in solving **your** problem do not equal theirs. It may be a legitimate questions but it does show that you do not understand the way the Apache+PHP environment works and how much it differs from the Browser+JavaScript environment works.

Comment: Its pretty clear question. How can you append a string to a `div` in html. Using jQuery, we can do this using `.append()`, but how to do this using PHP. One solution is posted, which is by using `echo` between the div which we want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On page load if the variable isset then show it as a first child of your div like this:

```
<div>
    <?php if(isset($mystring)) echo '<p class="test">'.$mystring.'</p>'; ?>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
</div>
```

but since this is php is served only on page refresh and of course you cannot have fancy js animations at once, some extra work needs to be done. If you want this to communicate with js add a class there and with js check its existence and then start its animations. This can be done like:

```
if($('.test').length > 0) {
    alert("This message is brought by php, great!!!");

    $('.test').on('click', function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
}
```